# Python : Can I separately use maintain and install ANN libraries and Image processing libraries in same project on windows10

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, pycharm

I want to use Opencv library for image processing which supports for python 2.7 and tensorflow library for ANN which supports for python 3.5 in the same project.But when I try to include opencv library after including tensor flow library in to pycharm,it shows an error.Is there any way to handle this problem?I have installed both python2.7 and python3.5 in my computer using anaconda.

Comment: Please follow these guidelines to ask your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both. Any errors you get are due to a bad installation of either Tensorflow of OpenCV. Best would be to find out what the exact problem is and post a new question to describe that.

Also: it would be a good idea to use Docker to get an image with OpenCV and tensorflow already installed. This is one I like: https://github.com/pkmital/CADL/tree/master/#docker-installation. It really removes the dependency and installation problems!